# How to give the user options to create new columns in the database

Tags: django

Is there a by the book way of allowing a user to add columns to a sites database table. For example, if the site was about animals, one user might want to have stats like, 'walks per week' and 'type of food' about their breed of dog. but another user might want to keep track of how much milk their goat is producing.

So if i have an 'Animal' class with come basic info. like, 'breed', 'animal name', 'DOB', 'DOD'. But then, in the front end have a form that will allow the users to add all the other columns they would like.

Is this possible? hope I've explained it well enough.

Comment: Normally the idea of columns is that these do *not* change over time. If you want to add dynamic attributes, you typically create an **E**ntity **A**tribute **V**alue (EAV) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model

Comment: Another option is to store a JSON blob in a column, and that blob is then a dictionary that stores "additional" columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@WillemVanOnsem already mentioned some good options in the comments. I'm going to chime in to say that modifying your schema's structure based on user input is an extremely bad idea and opens another avenue for abuse... for Django in particular, it means you either can't use the ORM's migration facilities for some of your models, or you probably have to do some really awful automation.

If your animal types are well-defined and consistent, you can consider (carefully) making them subclasses of the `Animal` model. Otherwise, this would be the simplest way to handle it (note that the following isn't valid code, it needs required arguments for the field types):

```
class AnimalAttribute(models.Model):
    animal = models.ForeignKey(Animal)
    name = models.CharField()
    value = models.CharField()
```

This works best if attributes aren't shared, e.g. users are directly inputting their animals' names and attributes, not picking from an existing list.

If you need to provide a normalized list of attributes users can pick from (actual EAV, which is something you should avoid if possible, since it moves some of your data structure from code into the data persistence layer), doing that in your models is a little more complex. For example:

```
class Species(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class SpeciesAttribute(models.Model):
    species = models.ForeignKey(Species)
    name = models.CharField()

class Animal(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    species = models.ForeignKey(Species)

class AnimalAttributeValue(models.Model):
    animal = models.ForeignKey(Animal)
    attribute = models.ForeignKey(SpeciesAttribute)
    value = models.CharField()
```